# Convert PNG to JP2 loss of quality

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick

I am converting a png file to jp2 format using imagemagick and even though I am configuring it to have quality 100, it still loses quality but only on the transparent gradient background and the borders of my image.

Command used in console:

```
magick input_image.png -quality 100 output_image.jp2
```

Below are only part of the input image and the output image where you can clearly see the loss of quality
[image: Input Image]
[image: Output Image]

I haven't found anything on imagemagick that explains this quality loss or what config could fix it.

*I have successfully used a third party site to convert my png to jp2 format and there was no loss of quality.

Comment: Unrelated, but avoid `magick convert`. If you have v7, which you clearly must as you have `magick`, the new syntax is just `magick INPUT operations OUTPUT`.

Comment: Alright thanks for the input ! I'll modify it in my question so it's more up to date

Comment: Try `-quality 0` if you want lossless.

Comment: What is your exact IM version and platform?  What delegate is installed to handle the JP2 images? Is it Jasper or OpenJPEG?  And what version. Does jp2 list in the Delegates when you do `magick -version`

Comment: @MarkSetchell Even with `-quality 0`, I'm still getting the same output

Comment: `Version: ImageMagick 7.0.9-14 Q16 x86_64 2020-01-06 https://imagemagick.org`
Yes, jp2 is listed in the delegates.

Comment: @fmw42 How do I check what delegate handles the jp2?

Comment: Try `magick -list configure |grep jp2`

Comment: I'm seeing this at the end:
`DELEGATES       bzlib mpeg freetype heic jng jpeg lcms lzma openexr openjp2 png tiff webp xml zlib`

Answer (score 3):

This works fine for me on IM 7.0.10.16 Q16 Mac OSX Sierra with OpenJPEG 2.3.1. (You need OpenJPEG 2.1 or higher)

[image]

```
magick img.png -quality 0 img.jp2
```

[image]

See https://imagemagick.org/script/jp2.php, but change "magick convert" to just "magick"

Comment: I am using IM 7.0.9-14. How do I check for the OpenJPEG version?

Comment: `magick -list format` At the end of the line for JP2 it will show a version and perhaps the tool name. On my system it lists `JP2* JP2       rw-   JPEG-2000 File Format Syntax (2.3.1)` So I have version 2.3.1

Comment: I'm getting these lines when running the command:
`JP2* JP2       rw-   JPEG-2000 File Format Syntax (2.3.1)
      JPC* JP2       rw-   JPEG-2000 Code Stream Syntax (2.3.1)` so I think I have the same version as you

Comment: That looks correct. So I am not sure where your issue arises. Did you try  -quality 0?  `magick input_image.png -quality 0 output_image.jp2`

Comment: Even with -quality 0 I'm still getting the same result :/

Comment: What is your platform?  What do you get from `magick -version`?

Comment: This is the complete log I receive:
`Version: ImageMagick 7.0.9-14 Q16 x86_64 2020-01-06 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: © 1999-2020 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI Modules OpenMP(3.1) 
Delegates (built-in): bzlib freetype heic jng jp2 jpeg lcms ltdl lzma openexr png tiff webp xml zlib`

Comment: I do not have an answer. I would suggest you post a bug report to https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/issues and include your platform, which you have not identified as I requested.

Comment: Alright thanks for your help. I'll log a bug and post back the solution when I have it !

Comment: Btw I am seeing that both images you linked are png, are you sure the second one is in jp2?

Comment: This forum does not allow jp2 uploads. So I had to convert the jp2 to png before uploading.